# Remove carriage returns in text file via the Terminal in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, sed

I’m trying to replace all carriage returns with a comma in a text file but I must be using the `sed` command improperly.

Since I can `echo -e "\x0D"`and yield the carriage return I tried `sed -e 's/open/'$(echo "\x0D")'/' 1.txt > 2.txt` to no avail. `1.txt` contains the carriage return, as you may have inferred. That command creates `2.txt` which contains text `x0D`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t really specific to Mac OS X; the same concept works on most any Linux/Unix OS. But while you could do this in [`sed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) (stream editor) you could also use [`tr`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tr.1.html) (translate characters) like this:

```
tr '\r' , < foo.txt
```

So if the contents of `foo.txt` are this:

```
123
456
789
```

The output of that `tr` command would then be:

```
123,456,789,
```

And to then output that command’s results to a file add `> bar.txt` to the end like this:

```
tr '\r' , < foo.txt > bar.txt
```

Comment: Carriage return (to answer OP's actual question) would be `\r`, not `\n`.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I am aware of this solution. I was looking for how to do it in Sed, if possible. I spent hours trying to use unicode or /r  with sed but couldn't figure out how. I probably should have saved you the time by posting that in my initial query. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is a better solution but you asked how to do it in `sed`.

with ansi -c quoting:

```
sed -E 's/'$'\r''/,/' file

sed $'s/\r/,/' file
```

without ansi -c quoting:

```
cr=$(printf '\r')
sed 's/'"$cr"'/,/' file
```